# createjs.Container's child doesn't trigger mouse event

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, easeljs, createjs

I have a movieclip nested in a container. Now I want to capture the mouse event of this movieclip but it doesn't work, I can only get mouse event of the container. I check event.target and it always gives me the container, and event.currentTarget is null. So now, I have to use getObjectUnderPoint() as a hack to check if mouse click on my movieClip or not.

Anyone got any idea what happens here? (this is the first time I get this problem, and I have been using easeljs for almost 2 years now)

Comment: Is by chance that movie clip flash?

Comment: What version of EaselJS is being used?

Comment: Yes, it's the movieclip built in Flash then generate it to javascript using Createjs Toolkit, and I am using the latest version 6.0.1.

Comment: Are you listening on both the container and the child? Version 0.6.1 does not have even bubbling (added in 0.7.0) so adding a container listener will block any child listeners.

Comment: I add listener to the child first but it doesn't work, so now I add listener to container and use getObjectUnderPoint() as a hack :(

Comment: Anyway, if I use 0.7.1 then it works, so I guess the 6.0.1 does have a bug somewhere. Thank you Lanny.